# Text.Parsec.Indent picking up non-indented content

Tags: haskell, parsec

```
import Control.Applicative
import Text.Parsec hiding (many, (<|>))
import Text.Parsec.Indent
data Markup = Tag String [Markup] deriving (Show)

run sourceName p source = runIndent sourceName (runParserT (many1 p <* eof) () sourceName source)

parser = withBlock ($) (tag <* spaces) parser
tag = Tag <$> many1 alphaNum
```

This mostly acts as I expect, but when I feed it a string like "hello\n\twoo\nhai hai" -- the second "hai" gets nested inside the first one, even though there is no indentation there?  What's going on here?

UPDATE: it looks like the following works as expected:

```
parser = withBlock ($) (tag <* inlineSpace <* newline <* inlineSpace) parser
inlineSpace = skipMany (satisfy isInlineSpace) <?> "inline white space"
isInlineSpace c = c /= '\n' && isSpace c
```

So, it seems like `withBlock` expects that the parser you give it will do a strict newline requirement itself, and does not check the line position of supposedly nested items.